# Geometry question about similarity

Tags: geometry

[image]

I know this question has something to do with similarity and drawing supplementary lines. But how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $[ABC]=\frac12 ab\cdot Sin C$, 
$$\frac{[AZY]}{[ABC]}=\frac{(1)(x)}{(x+1)^2} $$
$$\frac{[BZX]}{[ABC]}=\frac{(1)(x)}{(x+1)^2}$$
$$\frac{[CXY]}{[ABC]}=\frac{(1)(x)}{(x+1)^2} $$
So 
$$[ZXY]=\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+2x+1} [ABC]$$
$$[ZXY]=\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+2x+1} $$